# how to write the correct notation for Flip-Flop outputs: dashed-Q or not-Q?

Tags: ms-word

I'm struggling with Microsoft Word, characters.
I'm write an article about digital electronic circuits, and I'm describing some Flip-Flop use.

I'm not finding how to write the outputs of the Flip-Flops: NOT-Q (it's a "Q" with a dash over it).  I tried to find something into the character-map but I didn't find what I need

Here below in the screenshot from Wikipedia the character I'm looking for

[image: NOT-Q from Wikipedia]

Is there any way please?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or software support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: @KenWhite my apologizes. It's due the fact I didn't sleep this night so I made confusion. Sorry

Comment: Answered in Microsoft Community at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-word-how-to-write-the-correct-notation/a66d0b8b-7f1a-4de9-b7a6-028af6101eea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way, which is way cumbersome but it exists.

```
Insert > Equation > Insert New Equation > Accents
```

after a while, appear all the possible accents, included the ons I was looking for.
Writing any letter, will be accented as I asked for.

Or there is the Combined Diacritical Marks as described here:
http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/Overbar.htm